# Full Transitive Value Generation

Tags: java, macos, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to apply two-way synonym to the input data in CSV file

Sample Input :

```
Col A,Col B
sleep tightxjump highxjump low,Two-way
shell scriptxawk script,One-way
oops langxstructure lang,Two-way
```

Expected Output:

```
Col A.     
sleep tight=>jump high,jump low
jump high=>sleep tight,jump low
jump low=>jump high,sleep tight
shell script=>awk script
oops lang=>structure lang
structure lang=>oops lang
```

Ideally, if it is two way then there should be a full transitive relation.

I have tried it using awk and shell but not able to get it working. Any pointers would be appreciated.

PS: If any pointers give available on java also will be helpful

Comment: show your `awk --version`, Are you able to use/install `gawk`?

Comment: awk version 20070501

Comment: Awk given an error so i have installed gawk and the output is 3

Comment: Is there a reason why you want it to solve in Posix-Shell or awk? The former is really not suitable well for this type of problem. A modern awk (gawk) can be used, but you are going to parse a CSV File (even though it is one which uses an odd column delimiter), so it might be much easier to use a language which comes with a CSV parser. I'm using Ruby for this, but I think Perl or Python can be used equally well.

Comment: No special reason. I was bit comfortable with awk. I will give it a try with gawk. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1s/ \..*//p;/One-way/{s/ \..*//;s/x/=>/;s/x/,/;b};/Two-way/{s/ \..*//;s/(.*)x(.*)x(.*)/\1=>\2,\3\n\2=>\1,\3\n\3=>\1,\2/;b};d' file
```

This uses grouping and back references to tailor the output to the desired result. Of course the second column may have further values and will need to be hard coded in a similar vein to `Two-way`.

Following on from the change of data:

```
sed -r '1s/\..*//;t;/One-way/{s/\s+\S+$//;s/x/=>/;s/x/,/g;b};/\n/{/^([^x]*x).*\n\1/d;bb};/Two-way/{s/\s+\S+$//;s/.*/&\n&/;:b;s/^([^x]*)x(.*)\n/&\2x\1\n/;s/x/=>/;:a;ta;s/x(.*\n.*\n)/,\1/;ta;P;D}' file
```

As above for line 1 and `One-way`. `Two-way` makes a copy and cycles through the `x` delimited values until it repeats, when it deletes the values in the pattern space.

Comment: I am using Mac to test the command and i have used it with -i but getting the below error,

sed: 1: "1s/ \..*//;/One-way/{s/ ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: @Kumar, I'm sorry I can't reproduce your problem as I do not have a Mac. Firstly, are using GNU sed? Check by typing `sed --version` at the command line. Then check larger and larger parts of the sed script (in this case, parts of the one line) until the problem appears. I would hazard a guess that you have missed a closing delimiter somewhere. Good luck.

Comment: The command works fine for the column with more than 3 values seperated by **x**. But if the column contains only one separator, the command is not working. Any idea?

Comment: @Kumar perhaps you could supply further data and expected results to the above question?

Comment: I have edited the given example on the question itself on top. Thanks for the response

Comment: Now it is running in infinite loop with the first line itself

Comment: @Kumar when using the sample input I do not get this outcome.

Comment: The input is a csv file so i have modified the input like it a csv file

Answer (score 1):

As you have already installed `gawk` - here's advanced **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ print $1,$2$3; next }
    { split($1, a, "x") }
    {
        n=($3=="Two-way"? 4:2);
        for (i=1; i<n; i++) { 
            k=(i>1? i-1: i+1);
            printf "%s=>%s,%s\n", a[i], a[k], a[xor(i,k)] 
        } 
    }' file
```

The output:

```
Col A.
a1=>a2,a3
a2=>a1,a3
a3=>a2,a1
z1=>z2,z3
```

---

> The result of an `XOR` operation is 1 if either bit is 1, but not
>   both.
>
> **`xor(v1, v2 [, …])`**
>  
>      Return the bitwise `XOR` of the arguments. There must be at least two.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Roman. I am not getting the expected output from the script. 

Eg :

`ColA .                     ColB .       ColC`
`RugxRugsxWear .  Two-way .  xxx`

`Expected Output`

`ColA .`                     
`Rug=>Rugs,wear`
 `Rugs=>Rug,wear`
  `wear=> Rugs,Rug`

`Current Output`
    Rug=>Rugs,wear

Comment: @Kumar, most likely you are making some mistakes. Share the full screenshot